# Does Apple (APN) and Google (GCM) servers tell you what devices have registered for push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

To use the [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM) service, you need to know the registration ID of the device. The registration ID is created if the Android app uses the GCM client to register itself. Is it possible for a server which sends GCM messages to get a list of all registration IDs for a certain app, or do the apps have to send their IDs to the server (during login for instance) ? If yes, is it possible to get a list of all device tokens for all installed iPhone apps to send Apple Push Notifications (APN) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to get that list of registration IDs from Google nor that list of device tokens from Apple. Your app must send them to your server and your server must maintain that list.